# How can we feel Earth magnetic field if we are rotating with it?

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth

I know Earth have molten iron core and we should feel a magnetic force if we are stationary while Earth is spinning. But I'm curious how it is we can feel north and south poles so distinctly while we rotate with Earth?

Comment: The earth is not a solid magnet. Please read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field

Comment: Uh... it's not really clear why you would think the magnetic field goes away when you're rotating with the Earth. Are you perhaps mixing up the magnetic force with the Coriolis force (which would go away when you're _not_ rotating with the Earth)?

Comment: @knzhou I think OP might be referring to those questions that asks about reference frames of moving charges and the magnetic fields they generate. But in that case it's just whether the electric field appears to change while the magnetic field remains static or vise versa.

Comment: BTW *feel* is not a word used to describe measurable quantities.  For a solid magnet in the earth a compass would still find north and south. That the magnet of the earth depends on a liquid core changes the geographic on the earth location of the poles over the years.